# how do I perform multiplication to values in a column?

Tags: r

I am very new to R , just started this week, and I do not have any prior programming experiences, forgive me if I have phrased my questions with incorrect terms.

I have a table of data with 4 columns like this and I would like to multiply the last column values by -1 if they belong to group b while preserving the data structure.

```
Data:

 1. 21 A 0.1
 2. 78 B 0.9
 3. 29 B 0.3
 4. 71 A 0.5
```

Required outcome

```
 1. 21 A 0.1
 2. 78 B -0.9
 3. 29 B -0.3
 4. 71 A 0.5
```

Would someone kindly help me out here please?

Cheers
Dennis

Comment: You mean like `Data$V4 <- Data$V4 * ifelse(Data$V3 == "A", 1, -1)`?

Comment: There was a binary operator error message, but thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data:

```
df <- read.table(header=F, text=" 
 1. 21 A 0.1
 2. 78 B 0.9
 3. 29 B 0.3
 4. 71 A 0.5")
```

to change the values as required:

```
df[df[3] == "B", 4] <- df[df[3] == "B", 4] * -1
```

which is the same as

```
df$V4[df$V3 == "B"] <- df$V4[df$V3 == "B"] * -1

df
#  V1 V2 V3   V4
#1  1 21  A  0.1
#2  2 78  B -0.9
#3  3 29  B -0.3
#4  4 71  A  0.5
```

Basically you subset your data.frame `df` by column 3 (V3) where it is "B" and select column 4 of the subset and multiply it by -1. The rest is not changed.

Edit after comment:

If you want to change multiple columns, e.g. the second and fourth in the sample data, you can do:

```
df[df[3] == "B", c(2,4)] <- df[df[3] == "B", c(2,4)] * -1
df
#  V1  V2 V3   V4
#1  1  21  A  0.1
#2  2 -78  B -0.9
#3  3 -29  B -0.3
#4  4  71  A  0.5
```

Comment: May I ask , say if I have another column after V4, and if I want to do the same thing can I df$V4$V5[df$V3 =="B"] * -1 ?

Comment: @DennisTanEngKiat, in that case you could do: `df[df[3] == "B", c(4,5)] <- df[df[3] == "B", c(4,5)] * -1`. The `c(4,5)` will select the 4th and 5th columns in the subsetted data and apply the *-1 to it.

Comment: Thank you!, this community is awesome ! You have helped me tremendously for my data analysis sir/mdm, you have a nice day =)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are starting with:

```
> Data
  V1 V2 V3  V4
1  1 21  A 0.1
2  2 78  B 0.9
3  3 29  B 0.3
4  4 71  A 0.5
```

You can just do:

```
Data$V4 <- Data$V4 * ifelse(Data$V3 == "B", -1, 1)
```

Which would result in:

```
> Data
  V1 V2 V3   V4
1  1 21  A  0.1
2  2 78  B -0.9
3  3 29  B -0.3
4  4 71  A  0.5
```